# What's the file format of the output of mkfs.jffs2

Tags: embedded, linux

I am creating a file partition with the following command:

```
sudo mkfs.jffs2 -l -n -p -q -e 0x20000 -s 0x800 -d image/ -o sdcard/root/rootfs11182013.ambr.jffs2
```

I understand the commands and flags passed to the linux utility and what they do (I think).

However I don't know the file format that a jffs2 file is written in.

what is the format of the file created by mkfs.jffs2. Is it a binary? intel-hex? something more obscure?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a raw binary file containing a JFFS2 filesystem. You can use a tool such as `dd` to write this directly to a block device such as a SD card or MTD device for subsequent use in an embedded system.